# Is the range of weights in the optimized neural network in the genetic algorithm between 9 and -9 correct?

Tags: python

In fact, I use a neural network consisting of four layers of input and two hidden one for exit and I had 17 features to enter in order to classify or predict something, but the range of weights in the network should be between 1 and -1 and I used the pygad library but when I print the solutions it gives me the range  Between 9 and -9, I used the activation function ReLu for the two hidden layers and sigmoid **strong text** for the exit layer. Please help

Comment: There's no restriction in the weights of the network unless you are applying regularization constraints to them. Weights `W` are numbers that make `activation(Wx + b)` as close to the output as possible and the network without additional constraints will make `W` whatever value that'll give it the best results.

Answer (score 0):

The range of the weights exceeds the initial range (-1 to 1) because of the mutation. You can control the mutation in PyGAD using these 2 simple ways:

1. Set the `mutation_by_replacement` parameter to True. In this case, no gene will exceed the -1 to 1 range.
2. Set  `init_range_low=-0.5`  and  `init_range_high=0.5` but also set the 2 parameters `random_mutation_min_val` and  `random_mutation_max_val` to small values. For example, `random_mutation_min_val=-0.2` and  `random_mutation_max_val=0.2`. This option just tries to lower down the values created out of mutation. But there is possibility that the values get outside the -1 to 1 range.